# Migrating asp.net website to linux?

Tags: asp.net, linux

I have a asp.net website developed in VS 2010 and hosted on godaddy asp.net hosting enviroment. Now, i am setting my own server and need to migrate the same to linux. Do i need to do something extra in coding or installing any third party web server for dot net applications on Linux distro will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use Mono to run .NET on Linux.  Last time I looked it only supported .NET 2.0 although it is probably more advanced by now.

EDIT: It looks like Mono now supports .NET 4 features - see http://www.mono-project.com

Comment: thanks ....Will definitely give mono a shot for implementation. Also, i saw an Mono IDE, Is there any advantage of using Mono IDE over VS 2010 ?

Comment: It's worth noting that Mono's ASP.NET implementation (according to their website) does not include any .NET 4.0 controls, and only some supported ASP.NET 3.5 controls. So while the CLR up to .NET 4 may be supported, ASP.NET controls may be unavailable unless they can be imported via DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

An ASP.NET application can be run on a Linux server using Mono.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET. Support exists for ASP.NET Webforms (up to 2.0 at least, but probably higher too), MVC and AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You will need mono
http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

check http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page
its for run and develop .net in linux..